# how to redirect by .htaccess before the browser show massage "Your connection is not private"

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

my first question.

I would like to make a redirect before the site is displayed. 
Redirect is from a sub-domain to the folder in HTTPS protocol.

I wrote the code in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond% {HTTP_HOST} ^ sub.domain.com
RewriteRule ^ (. *) $ Https://www.domain.com/sub/$1 [L, NC, QSA]
```

But I get a browser page "Your connection is not private.". (As shown in the link)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WlqDW.jpg

Comment: Hi Refael, did you ever fix this? I have the same problem.

Comment: not yet unfortunately